# On Site.Com, how do you format output to show only whole numbers or integers?

Tags: site.com, outputtext

I've tried using the function that works in VisualForce --- {!FLOOR(myvar)} -- but it doesn't work in Site.com. Any idea how to format output variables in Site.com? I need to do a few in currency format, and a few as whole integers with commas.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Specifically, I have numbers coming out of SFDC onto my Site.com page looking like $239032.0 and like 3980229. How do I commify and format currency?